# Linear operators in the polynomial function space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let's say I have the standard monomial basis for P2:

{$1$, $x$, $x^2$}

And I have a linear operator $T: P_{2} \rightarrow P_{2}$ defined by:

$T(f)(x) = f'(x) + xf''(x) + x^2f''(x)$

Now I want to find $[T]_E$, the matrix of T relative to E.

I am confused about the notation. Namely, if I want to transform $x^2$ for example, do I substitute $x$ and $x^2$ with $x^2$ and $(x^2)^2$ respectively? Or is it meant to be interpreted as $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: The latter. $ $ $ $

Comment: E.g., $f(x) = x^2$ is a vector in the vector space and the action of $T$ on it is

$$T(f)(x) = 2x + x(2) + x^2(2) = 2x^2 + 4x$$

Comment: Thanks for that! It was a rather silly question, but thought that I should clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
T(1)=0, \space T(x)=1, \space T(x^2)=2x+x\times2+x^2\times2=2x^2+4x
$$

So the matrix $A_T$ of T is
$$   A_T=
  \left[ \begin{array}{}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 4 & 2 \\
  \end{array}  \right]
$$